# RPN calculator in C programming using Linked Lists

Tags: c, stack, calculator, postfix-notation

I have an assignment due to tomorrow and I have just started it.

I was asked to do an RPN calculator using linked lists.

The idea is I have to write an input string , like ( 25 35 + ) , and display the result using linked lists.

the structure used are

```
typedef struct {
int data;
struct cell *next;}cell;
```

and

```
typedef struct {
int positif;
struct cell *datas;
int ref;} num ;
```

in the example above , when I write 25 35 + , I have to stock the 25 as a number and push it into the stack , and do the same with the 35 , and when the operator is read , I do the operation calling 2 pops.

the problem is I do not know how to separate the numbers from the string when it reads a space.

this is my main

```
 char strIn[250];
num *lenumero = initialisation(); 
printf(">");                      
scanf("%s", &strIn);               

int i=0;
while(strIn[i] != '\0')
{
    /*Here I want to write the code that reads the string untill it finds a space ,
```

then it push the number before the space into the stack !

```
}
```

For example StrIn[0]=2  STrIn[1]=5  strIn[2]=(space)
So I will put 2 into a cell->data , 5 into the cell->next->data , and then I put all the cell into the cell used in the structure number, and push the structure number into the stack .

Thank you

Comment: Reverse Polish Notation?

Comment: @erip, it is a wonderful joke, to call reverse polish notation PRN!

Comment: The string `( 25 35 + )` is not valid postfix notation. There are no parentheses in postfix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in SergeyA's answer you can use `strtok` with a whitespace as delimter.

```
pointer = strtok(strIn, " ");
while(pointer != NULL) {
  printf("%s\n", pointer); // this is where you put your logic to push the number to the stack.
  pointer = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

If you want to test if it's an operator (i.e any of "+-/*") you can use `strchr`

```
const char *operators = "+-/*";
...
char *c = pointer;
if(strchr(operators, *c)) {
  printf("%c is in \"%s\"\n", *c, operators); // replace this with your logic to read from the stack and calculate the numbers with the given operator.
}else {
  while(*c) {
    printf("%c\n", *c); // this will print all the digits of the numbers
    c++;
  }
}
...
```

The problem with your code right now is that you're using `scanf("%s", strIn);` which will only read the first string until the space. What you should do is use `fgets` instead.

```
fgets(strIn, 25, stdin);
```

Here is a [live](https://ideone.com/hXeAXI) demo.

Comment: Okay I got it , now is there a possibility to take the 25 from the output as push it into a stack?

for example push(pointer[0],stack) .

Comment: @Zok yes you can use the function `atoi` to convert the string to an integer and use `push(atoi(pointer), stack)`. This will assume push takes an integer as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume it is a C assignment, not C++.

For polish notation, you do not need paranthises. Probably the easiest way would be to use `strtok()` to break input string into space-separated tokens, and than just check if token equals to '+' '-' '/' or '*'. If it does not, read it as integer (using sscanf, for example) and push as a number. Otherwise, push as an operation.